# При попытке импорта модуля из библиотеки, ранее установленной через npm, возникает ошибка импорта

Tags: javascript, npm, импорт, модули, node-modules

Импортирую момент из установленной через npm библиотеки. Выбрасывает ошибку: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "moment". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

VSCode высвечивает что модуль нашел: module "~/Desktop/Web3/node_modules/moment/ts3.1-typings/moment"
Свойство "moment" объявлено, но его значение не было прочитано.ts(6133)

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться почему в в браузере консоль не пускает)

Мой HTML:

```
 <body>
    <script src="./index.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

Мой JS:

```
import moment from "moment"
```

Мой PACKAGE.JSON:

```
{
  "name": "sc-methods",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "web3": "^1.7.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/modules-intro#ne-dopuskayutsya-golye-moduli

Но возможно проще будет добавить какую-нибудь сборку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня та же проблема с модулем howler. Мне помогло решение, подсказанное VS-code

```
npm i --save-dev @types/howler
```

Ошибка исчезла